ScrollView перекрывает нижнюю панель
У меня есть разметка, предоставлю ниже. Вот там есть ScrollView с элементами, а также нижняя панель навигации. При прокрутке страницы на низких разрешениях элементы перекрывают нижнюю панель. Как это исправить?


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="#1B1B1B"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".UpPage">
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_105sdp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@drawable/edittext_outline1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="409dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/main"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:paddingTop="15dp"
                android:src="@drawable/main" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/up_select"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:paddingTop="15dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/up_select"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/profile"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:paddingTop="15dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/profile" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/settings"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:paddingTop="15dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/setting" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/_20sdp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_20sdp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_20sdp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/jost"
                android:text="Улучшения"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_40sdp">

            </TextView>

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/ul1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="#242424"
                app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/one"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/jost"
                        android:text="Бонусы за клик - 3"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/_17sdp"></TextView>

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/_6sdp"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
                        android:background="#8c8c8c"></View>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/two"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_2sdp"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/jost"
                        android:text="Цена - 3000"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/_17sdp"></TextView>

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/_6sdp"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
                        android:background="#8c8c8c"></View>

                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                        android:id="@+id/buy1"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/_100sdp"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/_30sdp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_10sdp"
                        android:background="@drawable/white_button"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/jost"
                        android:text="Улучшить"
                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/_14sdp"></androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton>
                </LinearLayout>

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/ul2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="#242424"
                app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/three"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/jost"
                        android:text="Бонусы за клик - 5"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/_17sdp"></TextView>

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/_6sdp"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
                        android:background="#8c8c8c"></View>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/four"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_2sdp"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/jost"
                        android:text="Цена - 7000"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/_17sdp"></TextView>

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/_6sdp"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
                        android:background="#8c8c8c"></View>

                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                        android:id="@+id/buy2"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/_100sdp"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/_30sdp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_10sdp"
                        android:background="@drawable/white_button"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/jost"
                        android:text="Улучшить"
                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/_14sdp"></androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton>
                </LinearLayout>

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/ul3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_20sdp"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="#242424"
                app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/five"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/jost"
                        android:text="Бонусы за клик - 7"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/_17sdp"></TextView>

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/_6sdp"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
                        android:background="#8c8c8c"></View>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/six"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_2sdp"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/jost"
                        android:text="Цена - 15000"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/_17sdp"></TextView>

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/_6sdp"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
                        android:background="#8c8c8c"></View>

                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                        android:id="@+id/buy3"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/_100sdp"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/_30sdp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_10sdp"
                        android:background="@drawable/white_button"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/jost"
                        android:text="Улучшить"
                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/_14sdp"></androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton>
                </LinearLayout>

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>




